# asynchronously evaluating whole python or perl buffer

Tags: python, perl, emacs, elisp

I've written some functions attached to my F5 and F6 keys so that when pressed, these evaluate the buffer contents for perl or python.

```lisp
;; F5 = perlevaluatie
(defun perl-eval ()
  "Run whole buffer as Perl code"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "perl") ; feeds the region to perl on STDIN
)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'perl-eval)

;; F6 = pythonevaluatie
(defun python-eval ()
  "Run whole buffer as Python code"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "python")
)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'python-eval)
```

However, when I use these functions for a script that keeps running for long times, emacs hangs. Appending an & does not help as with the `shell-command` function. Does anybody know a way to make the `shell-command-on-region` asynchronous?

Thanks in advance,

Marten

Comment: Did you take a look at [quickrun](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-quickrun)? I found it very convenient for testing my scripts on emacs.

Comment: You cannot use `shell-command-on-region` asynchronously in emacs 24.3.1. There the shell is invoked only with the command `call-process-region` which is synchronous. To have an asynchronous command you would need `start-process` and sentinels that observe the execution of the started process. An interesting question is: What happens if the input region is modified during the run of the script?

Answer (score 0):

I use `compile` for this: `M-x compile`, `perl <file-name>`. After the first run you can use recompile to rerun it.

Slightly more time to type the file's name but you gain a lot of nice stuff, and it's asynchronous of course.

Edit: Bonus helper function to automatically use compile the first time then recompile:

```lisp
(defun my-recompile ()
  "Recompile if possible, otherwise compile current buffer."
  (interactive)
  ;; If recompile exists do it, else compile
  (if (fboundp 'recompile) (recompile)
    (compile "make -k")))
```

and in the appropriate hook bind something like

```lisp
(local-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'my-recompile)
(local-set-key (kbd "<C-f5>") 'compile)
```

Comment: I don't understand? Perl or python are scripting languages, so why should they be compiled? Can't they be run, without saving the buffer to a file?

Comment: @MartenBE `compile` is probably a misleading name: it can be used to run any shell command. You do have to save it, but I've never found that to be an issue (since you can set `compile` to automatically save the buffer).